# How to get a specific child from an XML file and show its children on a div with PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml

So, I have an XML file that looks like this (The names are fictional):

```
<myxmlfile>
  <infos>
     <item>
        <itemChild1>foo1</itemChild1>
        <itemChild2>foo2</itemChild2>
     </item>
     <item>
        <itemChild1>foo1</itemChild1>
        <itemChild2>foo2</itemChild2>
     </item>
     <item>
        <itemChild1>foo1</itemChild1>
        <itemChild2>foo2</itemChild2>
     </item>
     <item>...</item>
     <item>...</item>
     <item>...</item>
     <item>...</item>
     <item>...</item>
     <item>...</item>
  <infos>
</myxmlfile>
```

My goal is to take for example ONLY the third `<item>`, and show on my browser its children. How can I achieve that?

So far I have this:

PHP

```
<?php
$divId = 0;
$url ='myxml.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die ("Can't connect to URL");
?>
```

Comment: Have you read the [SimpleXML documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) ? I'm sure you'll find everything that you're looking for in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to access the node values of your XML would be to use the object operator plus your node name e.g. `$xml->myxmlfile`

```
$xml_data = '
    <myxmlfile>
      <infos>
         <item>foo1</item>
         <item>foo2</item>
         <item>foo3</item>
         <item>foo4</item>
         <item>foo5</item>
      </infos>
    </myxmlfile>
';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_data);

foreach($xml->infos->item as $k=>$v) {

    echo $v . '<br>';

}
```

**Output:**

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
foo5
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: It is not what i need, You see, those <item> have more tags in them, for example <myxmlfile><infos><item><itemChild1>. I only want the third one, not all the list. How can i achive that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) with [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) queries. Your question doesn't exactly state what you're trying to achieve, so here's a couple of examples:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// query 3rd item and get the first match
$item = $xpath->query("/myxmlfile/infos/item[3]")->item(0);
// dump item as an XML
echo $doc->saveXML($item) . "\n";
// iterate all children of the item and work with nodes directly
foreach ($xpath->query("./*", $item) as $node) {
    printf("%s has a value of %s\n", $node->nodeName, $node->nodeValue);
}
// iterate all children and dump nodes as an HTML
foreach ($xpath->query("./*", $item) as $node) {
    echo $doc->saveHTML($node) . "\n";
}
```

This prints the following:

```
<item>
    <itemChild1>foo1</itemChild1>
    <itemChild2>foo2</itemChild2>
</item>
itemChild1 has a value of foo1
itemChild2 has a value of foo2
<itemChild1>foo1</itemChild1>
<itemChild2>foo2</itemChild2>
```